# How to check that AlertDialog was destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have opened AlertDialog from fragment, after that I closed AlertDialog and returned the data to parent fragment.

== Parent fragment code

```
 @Override
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt("type", 1100); 

    DialogFragment dialog = AddDialog.newInstance();
    dialog.setArguments(arguments);
    dialog.setTargetFragment(this, CREATE_PAYMENT);
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

== AlertDialog code

```
@Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_add, null);

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setView(view);

    builder.setView(view).setPositiveButton(R.string.btnSend, null);

    final AlertDialog d = builder.create();
    d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Button b = d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // .... do something

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("payment", operation);
                        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(),
                                Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return d;
 }
```

After press Ok I've returned to parent fragment, done some operations and replace parent fragment to another one.
  But unfortunately during replacing fragments there is trembling of new fragment because I think AlertDialog doesn't destroyed from main Activity after dismiss();

I think so because I don't have such a trembling with the same fragment in other parts of program where there isn't AlertDialog.

== Parent fragment code

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            // ... do something

           Sign newFragment = Sign.newInstance(new_operation);
           FragmentManager fragmentManager =   getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
           fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main, newFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

           break;
        }
    }
}
```

How to replace fragment just after AlertDialog has been closed and destroyed.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your dialog

```
d.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // Replace your fragment             
    }
});
```

or

```
d.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        // Replace your fragment
    }
});
```

Above callback methods will be called as soon as dialog is canceled/dismissed.

Comment: No, unfortunatly I've the same trembling

Comment: One more. I added  @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {} because I use DialogFragment and your example didn't work at my code